# Pass function reference to a separate Javascript file for callback

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have created a common Javascript file for all my ajax calls. I am trying to use this as a common way to keep track of all ajax calls. Below is the code for the same.

```js
function doAjax(doAjax_params) {
    var url = doAjax_params['url'];
    var requestType = doAjax_params['requestType'];
    var contentType = doAjax_params['contentType'];
    var dataType = doAjax_params['dataType'];
    var data = doAjax_params['data'];
    var beforeSendCallbackFunction = doAjax_params['beforeSendCallbackFunction'];
    var successCallbackFunction = doAjax_params['successCallbackFunction'];
    var completeCallbackFunction = doAjax_params['completeCallbackFunction'];
    var errorCallBackFunction = doAjax_params['errorCallBackFunction'];

       //Make the ajax call
    $.ajax({
        url: getBaseURL() + url,
        crossDomain: true,
        type: requestType,
        contentType: contentType,
        dataType: dataType,
        data: data,
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            console.log(typeof successCallbackFunction);
            debugger
            //if (typeof successCallbackFunction === "function") {
                successCallbackFunction(data);
            //}
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            if (typeof errorCallBackFunction === "function") {
                errorCallBackFunction(errorThrown);
            }

        }
    });
    }
```

This code takes a list of parameters and creates an ajax request based on the parameteres. This code is saved in a file `APIHandler.js`.

I am trying to call this function from multiple files. An example call is below.

```js
function RedirectToDashboard() {
    var params = $.extend({}, doAjax_params_default);
    params['url'] = `profile/5`;
    params['successCallbackFunction'] = `testsuccess`
    doAjax(params);

}

function testsuccess() {
    alert("success");
}
```

**When I run this function, I am able to make the call successfully. The only issue comes with the reference to callback function. `console.log(typeof successCallbackFunction);` returns string instead of function.**

I thought maybe order of JS made a difference. I am loading `APIHandler.js` and then the page specific js. And this ajax call happens at button click, so both JS files are loaded before the ajax call is made.

Other than that, I think maybe I am sending the parameters wrong. That might be causing JS to consider function name as string. But I checked most of the google suggestions on how to pass function, and it seems it needs just the name.

Is there anything else that I might be missing here?

Comment: you're passing a string `'testsuccess'` to the param...

Comment: Yeah, I noticed the same after posting. Stupid mistake. Should I leave the question as is, for future reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Damn it. I just figured out why it was causing the error. I used quotes when assigning the callback function. Right after posting the question, I realised what was wrong.

`params['successCallbackFunction'] = 'testsuccess'`

is supposed to be changed to

`params['successCallbackFunction'] = testsuccess`

Comment: think of [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)